# PHP ssh2_exec() not working

Tags: php, ssh

I want connect and run command on a remote device with SSH from my server. When I try the command in SSH client like Putty, it works flawlessly. But when I write it using a PHP script, the command will not be executed. Any ideas?

```
<?php
  $host = "192.168.0.184";
  $user = "user";
  $password = "password";
  $cmd = "reboot";
  $ssh = ssh2_connect($host);
  $sshLogin = ssh2_auth_password($ssh, $user, $password);
  $sshExec = ssh2_exec($ssh, $cmd);
?>
```

In device log, I can see user is authenticated successfully but nothing else.

Comment: Any errors produced by this?

Comment: No, just blank page... there must be somethink with exec, because as I wrote, when I go to the device log, I can see SSH was connected and autheticated.

Comment: Do slightly less drastic commands (eg ls) work?

Comment: I have limited sort of commands which I can use. LS is not supported. Its not standard linux shell. I tried many of supported commands and now I am trying for debug only reboot command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code... used interactive shell with sleep after command. And working OK.

```
<?php
        echo "SSH connection: ";
        if (!($resource=@ssh2_connect("your_host"))) {
                echo "[FAILED]<br />";
                exit(1);
        }
        echo "[OK]<br />";

        echo "Athetication: ";
        if (!@ssh2_auth_password($resource,"your_user","your_password")) {
                echo "[FAILED]<br />";
                exit(1);
        }
        echo "[OK]<br />";

        echo "Shell: ";
        if (!($stdio = @ssh2_shell($resource,"xterm"))) {
                echo "[FAILED]<br />";
                exit(1);
        }
        echo "[OK]<br />";
        $command = "reboot\n";
        fwrite($stdio,$command);

        sleep(1);

        while($line = fgets($stdio)) {
                flush();
                echo $line."<br />";
        }

        fclose($stdio);
?>
```